# Installing fourier-orns font in Texlive 2016 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: fonts, ubuntu, texlive-2016

I upgraded `Tex Live` and `Ubuntu`. Now I have `TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) kpathsea version 6.2.2` on `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`. When I compile already test document, I get the following error:

```
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for fourier-orns. mktexpk: perhaps fourier-orns is missing from the map file.
```

I guess `fourier-orns` font is missing or not in the path. Any help to figure out the problem will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
```

**Edited**

I also tried

```
sudo tlmgr install fourier
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.imsc.res.in/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr install: package already present: fourier
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra
texlive-fonts-extra is already the newest version (2016.20160520-1~ubuntu16.04.1york1).
```

Still it throws the same error. Any thoughts.

Comment: might be easiest to install `apt-file` and use it to ask debian which `.deb` file provides `fourier-orns.sty`, TeXLive in Ubuntu/Debian is split up into many `.deb` packages. Figuring out which to use is rather hard. One of the reasons I tend to recommnd installing the upstream TeXLive instead. Alternatively you can jsut install all TeX Live stuff from Ubuntu/Debian by installing `texlive-all`

Comment: Your edits don't seem to use any of the suggestions @daleif made.

Comment: So you would recommend to install `texlive-all` from scratch, @cfr and daleif. If yes, then what is the best way to install `TeXLive 2016`. Thanks

Comment: If space is an issue, try installing `apt-file` it is a great search tool to figure out which `dep`  file provides which physical file.

Comment: No. I would recommend removing all traces of your current installation and using upstream's installer. However, if you don't want to do that, then follow one of the options suggested by @daleif. But only go the cherry-picking route if you have no choice. It is *much* easier to work with a complete installation.

Comment: @cfr some people do prefer getting good their stuff from the Linux dist. And it seems Norbert does update it regularly. However, I do agree and prefer the upstream version. See the Debian page for texlive (Google vanilla texlive, it will tell you how to build an equivs package that covers all the Debian packages, such that subsequent installation of stuff like editors that depends on (or recommends) texlive, does not cause installation of the Debian texlive stuff.

Comment: @daleif I know. But I still wouldn't want to use it, personally, so I cannot in good conscience recommend it. This is not a criticism of Norbert by any means. (In any case, I wouldn't use Ubuntu or Debian by choice, although I have used Debian when I had almost no choice. But still upstream for TL.)

Comment: @cfr what is your beef with Ubuntu/Debian?

Comment: @daleif I don't like Ubuntu's philosophy. I have nothing against Debian's philosophy but I am not keen on their technical decisions. I don't much like `apt`, for example. It is hard to say this or that is wrong with it. But the way things are done makes the system very complicated. I don't like dealing with unnecessary complications - I'd prefer to save my energies for the necessary ones. I don't have anything against Debian, though. It is just a matter of personal preference. I'm happier using an alternative - since there is plenty of choice, I prefer an alternative I'm comfortable with.

Comment: @daleif To summarise: I have nothing at all against Debian. Nothing. Any more than I have anything against Gnome or TeXStudio. I just don't wish to use it given that there are other options I prefer.

Comment: You're wasting a bounty here. @daleif already made 2 suggestions for ways you might solve this and I made 1. Presumably you don't like them, but it isn't clear why.

Comment: Disclaimer: I have no experience at all with TeX on Ubuntu; but I was reflecting on the fact that `tlmgr` claims that the `fourier` *package* (which is not the same thing as the fourier *fonts*, of course!) is present on your system. So I thought that you might be experiencing a configuration problem. Have you checked the first obvious thing, that is, that the `fourier-orns` entry is actually missing from your map file, as the warning you get suggests? (I bet it is, otherwise you wouldn’t be getting the warning!) And what happens if you type `kpsewhich fourier-orns.tfm` at the terminal prompt?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti The fonts are themselves part of the package. `tlmgr info --list fourier` for details. I don't know enough about Ubuntu/Debian to have any idea how it manages this. But if `fourier` is installed with `apt`, will `tlmgr` recognise it? Presumably it must. If so, and if the user has installed any fonts with `tlmgr` prior to installation of `fourier`, will the user's `.map` files be updated? It's a bit hard to see how they could be. (`tlmgr` shouldn't be run with `sudo`, I don't think as it is using `user` mode.)

Comment: In regular TL, I'd just say never install fonts into a personal tree. But I suspect that is what you get here even if you run `sudo tlmgr` because I'm not sure how it might work. Unless it uses a local tree - but then it says it drops to `user` mode, so presumably not. ??

Comment: @cfr: The fonts are part of the package, sure! (And I’ve got TeXLive Utilty, too… Late hour! :-) But the point I was trying to make is that although the package is installed (`tlmgr` says so), nonetheless the system is misconfigured: as far as I know, `mktexpk` would not be run, unless the entry for `fourier-orns` were missing from the map file. Couldn’t this be the consequence of a typical “map file in `$TEXMFHOME/web2c/`” situation? **EDIT:** note that in this case, even reinstalling the distribution might prove useless.

Comment: @MYaseen208: So I think you should: 1) clarify whether you are using pdfTeX or TeX + dvip* + … (the banner you posted says [`This is`] `TeX 3.14159265`…, but perhaps you dropped the `pdf`, since you say that the error occurs “when [you] *compile*”); 2) If you are running pdfTeX, report the answer your system gives to the command `kpsewhich pdftex.map`.  When we know the answers to this, we can continue to investigate.

Comment: @cfr: I actually meant “…the consequence of a typical ‘map file in `$TEXMFHOME/texmf-var/`’ situation”, of course!

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Do you mean `TEXMFVAR` rather than `TEXMFHOME`? `pdftex.map` in `TEXMFVAR` is often a problem, but it is harder to inadvertently get it into `TEXMFHOME`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45240/discussion-between-gustavo-mezzetti-and-cfr).

Comment: @MYaseen208 and `updmap` and `updmap-sys` were exhausted?

Comment: Starting from a fresh Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS installation, after `sudo aptitude install texlive-fonts-extra texlive-lang-french latexmk`, the [demo file obtained from CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/fourier-GUT/doc/latex/fourier/fourier-orns.tex) compiles properly with `latexmk -pdf fourier-orns.tex`.  There must be something wrong with your Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out by installing `texlive-full` through

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive-2016
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```